# Select users where timecard submitted

Tags: elixir, ecto

Say I have some users:

```
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | bob   |
| 2  | bill  |
| 3  | barry |
```

these users submit timecards each week:

```
| id | date         | user_id | week |
|----|--------------|---------|------|
| 1  | '2018-01-01' | 1       | 1    |
| 2  | '2018-01-02' | 1       | 1    |
| 3  | '2018-01-01' | 2       | 1    |
```

I now want to write an ecto query which returns a list of users who have submitted timecards for a given week.

I have tried the following:

```
def get_users_with_timecards(week) do
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]

  from(u in User,
    join: tc in Timecard,
    where: tc.week== ^week,
    distinct: u.id
  )
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

running the following, I get:

```
iex>get_users_with_timecards(1) |> length
3
```

I would like to return only the first 2 users - those who have submitted timecards.

Comment: Select from `Timecard`, then join `User`, not vice versa.

Comment: I am actually working with a "base" query which starts with `query = from(u in User)`. Then works off of that... `from(u in query, ...)`

Comment: Then `right_join` `Timecard`. `from u in User` already returns all the users, why would you expect them to be filtered afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the `on:` part in `from/2`. The following works for me:

```
def get_users_with_timecards(week) do
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]

  from(u in User,
    join: tc in Timecard,
    on: u.id == tc.user_id,
    where: tc.week== ^week,
    distinct: u.id
  )
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If your schema set up a `belongs_to` and a `has_many` relationship, you can also do..

```
from(u in User,
join: tc in assoc(u, :timecards),
where: tc.week== ^week,
    distinct: u.id
  )
  |> Repo.all()
```